# How to make a key stroke through code or a command in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-foxpro, foxpro

`KEYBOARD '{CTRL+LEFTARROW}'`

In Foxpro this command will make a Keystroke of Control+Left Arrow.  Is there any command or codes in vb.net, instead of the `KEYBOARD` command in Foxpro?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `SendKeys.Send("{^LEFT}")` when we are talking about [WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AlexB. The `^` needs to be outside of the brackets like this `SendKeys.Send("^{LEFT}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputSimulator class from codeplex:

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com